# Interactive testing with TestAgent on vNext

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, tfs-2015

I set up an Build Definition on the vNext Build System with the TestAgent Deployment Task and the actual "Test using Test Agent" Task.
The build agent is a virtual machine in our company Domain, the tests run on another virtual machine in a local Workgroup.
I checked the "interactive process" checkbox at the TestAgent Deployment Task, because my test start a desktop application and uses Ranorex UI Automation to interact with the Desktop application.

So far the deployment of the test agent works fine. 
 I can also see the test agent process (DTAExecutionHost), the vstest process and the process of the desktop application when I run the build definition. The odd thing is, that I can't see the UI of my desktop application when I'm logged in via Remote Desktop or the vmware Remote Console.

Comment: How did you launch the desktop application? I launch app via "System.Diagnostics.Process pr = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc.exe");" during the test and the app ui can be displayed when I remote login via Remote Desktop.

Comment: I made a simple Example which just starts the calculator via System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc.exe").  I get the same result: I see the calc.exe in the task manager with my currently logged in username, but the UI of the calculator doesn't show up on the desktop

Comment: I see "DTAExecutionHost" is run when "interactive process" is unchecked and the UI does not show. And "DtaAgentExecutionService" is run when "interactive process" is checked and the UI shows. Can you check the settings for "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" step?

Comment: For testing purposes I unchecked the "interactive process" combobox. Then the TestAgentConfiguration Powershell script tries to install the DTaAgentExecutionService. This fails with the log message "Service failed to install. Error: 0".

Comment: You can download the latest test agent and install it on remote machine manually. And then use TestAgent Deployment Task to configure the interactive mode.

Comment: I think the installation is not the problem. Tee "TestAgentInstall.ps1" scripts runs fine.

Comment: The error I mentioned above happens when the TestAgentDeployment Task runs the "TestAgentConfiguration.ps1" script.  I don't get it why it fails to install the DTAgentExecutionService:http://pastebin.com/HQFmEVQf

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the same account to login the remote machine as the test agent is using.

Comment: The test agent already uses the same account as me when I login via RemoteDesktop. The test agent seems to be configured correct as a interactive process because the DTAExecutionHost is used instead of DTAExecutionService.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the DTAgentExecutionService was failing to install. I fixed it by providing the full username in my test machine group, which I edited in:
    http://...TfsCollectionUrl/Project/Team/_machines.

For my test VM, I changed the entry under username from "myUserName" to "machineName\myUserName" and reran the Build, which ran successfully this time.

FYI, I checked "Interactive Process" in Agent Configuration under the "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" task, and I can view my UI tests while connected to my test VM through Hyper-V Manager.